# Window Position Makes Applications Open Off-Screen | Mavericks

Tags: macos, display, plist

I am having trouble with applications reopening halfway off-screen on my second display in Mavericks.

Is this a bug? or a preferences/settings issue?

I like many apps to launch on the second display. 
I set this by: Dock > Options > Assign to Desktop on Display 2
This works, but apps always remember their maximized position a few inches from the left side of the display, effectively hiding half of the window off-screen.

If I drag the window back to the 0,0 position and then close it, Mavericks does not remember the position the next time a new window opens.

I've seen a few people discuss this issue, and most recommendations say to turn off 'Displays Have Separate Spaces' in Sys Pref > Mission Control.
While this works, it basically brings settings back to pre-Mavericks conditions and breaks full-screen support.

From what I understand, now that each display has its own spaces, Mavericks is only acknowledging the dimensions of the largest display. If one display is smaller than other, it will cut windows off when you open them on the smaller display, because it remembers a window position as if it were opening on the largest display.

I can clarify if that doesn't make sense.

Mainly, I just want to know, is this a bug Apple has not fixed yet with Mavericks, or is there something I'm missing here? I am surprised more people are not talking about this if it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that you can move the app window if you position the mouse over the edge to get the horizontal or vertical resize arrows.  The trick is to move the mouse horizontally if you have the vertical resize arrows or vertically if you have the horizontal resize arrows.  It is a bit tricky, but it works on Mavericks 10.9.x  This trick does not work with the diagonal resize arrows.  The trick works better if you get the resize arrows the furthest away from the window without turning back into a normal pointer.  You can practice this trick on any window, off screen or not.

Comment: Also, if you hold down the option button when resizing, the window resizes on both sides.  This *does* work with diagonal resizing.  Again, this works on all windows, off screen or not.  You can try it out now.

Comment: While this does not prevent the app window from opening outside of the screen, it does make correcting this issue dead simple. Once you do it a couple of times, any app halfway off the screen is just a mouse movement or two way from being wherever you wish the window to be located.

Hope this helps! I rezzed this thread to help others that Google this issue. I accidentally found this solution in a moment of frustration.